# How to restrict which colliders are triggered?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Sorry if similar questions have already been asked.

I have a character that can hold up a shield to block incoming damage. The character has a circle collider for his body space. The shield has a box collider that blocks off a portion of whatever direction he's facing, and it's only enabled when the player is holding down a button. My enemies have weapons surrounded by triggered box colliders which are enabled when they decide to attack.

So, my problem is that when my character is attacked while shielding, sometimes his body collider is detected and sometimes his shield collider is detected. I can't find any consistency no matter what I try.

[Screenshots] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/b76Yw.png)

[Code] https://gist.github.com/siketh/2401454977d10ed7699b

I've been struggling with this all day and need another set of eyes. This isn't a serious project so if you need to see anything else I'm happy to post more code or explain more of my design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because the weapon intersects with both the character and the shield at the same time. There are great tools in Unity if you want to see if that's the case.

1. Notice that Unity has "Play", "Pause" and ***"Play one step"*** buttons at top of the editor window. You can pause the game with `Debug.Break();` instantly at the moment player fires or swings the weapon. Then you can watch what's happening step by step. Select the character, the shield and the weapon so that you can see their colliders in action. This way you can see what collides with what exactly step by step.
2. Similarly you can see the action in slow motion by adjusting time scale. Something like `Time.timeScale = 0.1f;`

To prevent this,

1. You may want to look at `continuous collision` though I've always failed to use it properly in Unity.
2. You may want to utilize more physics layers. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html
3. You may want to detect collisions by using raycasts.
4. You can enlarge the shield and reduce the weapon swing speed or bullet speed. So that it's impossible to penetrate through shield.
5. You can decrease the period of FixedUpdate calculations so weapon movement will be smoother and there will be less penetrations.
   http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html
6. There is a high probability that you are detecting both weapon-to-shield and weapon-to-player collision in one step. So why not postpone the decision one FixedUpdate later. So that you can check if there was only weapon-to-player collision or both collisions. If weapon-to-shield collision detected in previous update, then you know player hit the shield no matter if weapon passed through the shield or not.
7. Let's say there is no way you can detect if weapon hits the shield or the player. By using some simple geometry, you can check if the attack is coming from the direction of the shield or not.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your thought out response. I really appreciate it. While I haven't quite solved it yet, I know several of the approaches you mentioned will work. Just trying to figure out how to do it without having to rework too many things and create new problems :)